# javascript for saving the message automatically 

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a asp htmleditor where the user will enter any text or a message...is there any javascript to save the message every 5 seconds as drafts in vb.net .

Comment: why every 5 seconds? i mean why don't you do it after clecking save button for example?

Comment: and you nead a database to save that data or array or ....

Comment: save in database....and i need it for every 5 seconds because here we have a problem of system crashing,power cutoffs and they cannot afford a ups for every user. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your question is not much clear, I am assuming that you want to save the text in the database and let's say the htmleditor is some simple text area. So, you need to do two things to save the texts of the htmleditor as draft.

1. Do a ajax call which will do the saving part.
2. Use javascript function `setInterval()` for doing ajax call repeatedly for some given (in your case 5 sec) time interval.

So let's say `saveHtmlEditorText()` is the function which does an ajax call to save the text. And now you have to initialize the `setInterval()`, you can use the `document.ready()` to initialize.

`setInterval("saveHtmlEditorText()",5000);`

You can see more about `setInterval()` [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/).

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I have to save the text in database. I am sorry i did not mention that. And thank you for your quick response. I will definitely give a try on that.

Comment: Never pass strings to setInterval, you can pass the function directly:

setInterval(saveHtmlEditorText, 5000);